# Mystery Syntax Error Pine Script Function

Tags: pine-script

I am struggling! I am brand new to Pine Script. So, I apologize for missing anything.

I'm trying to declare a function (user defined) in order to call later in request.security without a mutable variable error. No matter what I try, I keep getting "syntax error at input '>='".

This is what I have the error on.
I've checked the user manual, and I cannot figure it out.

```
frup_func() >=
    up = high[HighWickInput]>=high[HighWickInput]+1 and high[HighWickInput]>=high[HighWickInput]+2 and high[HighWickInput]>=high[HighWickInput]-1 and high[HighWickInput]>=high[HighWickInput]-2
    frup = 0
    frup := up ? HighWickInput : frup[1]
```

I tried including the HighWickInput variable in the function as well--so that all things that this function could POSSIBLY touch were there, but that didn't work either. I also don't think that the up variable needs to be in there, but I don't know.

I'm trying to achieve something like [this.](https://quantnomad.com/faq-cannot-use-a-mutable-variable-as-an-argument-of-the-security-function-how-to-fix/)

What have I missed or messed up?

Thanks for any guidance!

Answer (score 0):

User functions are declared with the `=>` operator, not `>=` :)